# Is there any way to connect MVC project with Sql server without using Ado.net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ado.net

Recently started using MVC and I think I got the base of it. I know basic C# and not much about web dev or SQL stuff and I agree that I am lacking knowledge on some basic stuff as well.

Past 2 weeks I searched what MVC is, how to use it etc and I think I understand it. Let's say there's a factory and it produces some stuff and writes down how much stuff it produced in KGs to SQL every hour. What I am trying to do is making a web app, that gets that data from an MSSQL server, and shows it as a graph. I did this using ADO.NET Entity Framework
[and looks like this (with Models/Entity stuff)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdnoW.png).
and [in View like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2jWU.png)

But there is a problem I have. The videos I learned it from using ADO.NET (or Entity Framework?. Don't really know what is what at this point tbh.) as you can see in pictures but **I need to use some sort of connection string because what happens is, the "Production Factory" won't give me the database access itself remotely, but they will give me a connection string and column names I will use. So I will program based on those (and creating a "fake" db on my own just to work with) so the web app will work on their machines without changing anything after I compiled it.**

Someone before me made something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbrg2.png) but whatever I search online leads me to ADO.NET EF method and not this, I don't know how should I search this since I don't know the name of the method he uses there.

Or, is it possible to configure this ADO.NET EF to what I am trying to get originally, configuring in a way before publishing so it works out of the box when delivered to local machines of the production factory?

Is it possible to learn this power? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to replicate the last image, you can start googling for "datareader" in .net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: "Connect SQL" as in connect to MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh Yes, the customer gives me a connection string and columns in db, I recreate the db in dev env to work with it but, before I "publish" it I change connection string to their connection string. So when they set the app on their local machine, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ado.net with something like this.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
        string strConString = @ "Data Source=WELCOME-PC\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True";  
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConString)) {  
            con.Open();  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblStudent", con);  
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            da.Fill(dt);  
        }  
        return dt;
```

For more details see the following link - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/francissvk/crud-operations-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-ado-net/